# C# Call an object from concatenated text

Tags: c#, controls, userform

I was trying to call multiple labels with multiple names from a for loop, but the thing is that i dont want to use the "foreach" to loop trough all the controls.

I want to make a direct reference to it, for example :

```
for(ai = 2; ai < 11 ; ai ++)
{
    this.Controls("label" + ai).Text = "SomeRandomText";
}
```

How can i do this?

I already tried to find this question on the net, but all i find are answers with "foreach" loops.
Thanks!!

Comment: can't do this in c#. However you should look into reflection

Comment: this.Controls.Item["label" + ai.ToString()].Text

Comment: Are your labels named "lable2" through "label11"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your labels are named "lable2" through "label10", then you can do it like this:

```
for(int ai = 2; ai < 11 ; ai++)
{
    this.Controls["label" + ai].Text = "SomeRandomText";
}
```

Comment: This might work but if you change the name of your label then the code will fail and you will not get any compile time checks.

Comment: That's true. But It seems that OP wants to target labels with specific names.

Comment: Thanks! To think that i only needed to change () for []... Looks like i have a long way to go !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is not dependent on the control's name so you are free to change the name of the label at any point in time without breaking your code.

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is Label)
    {
        int index;
        if (control.Tag != null && int.TryParse(control.Tag.ToString(), out index) && index >= 2 && index < 11)
        {
            ((Label)control).Text = "SomeRandomText";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, all you need to do is assign a value between 2 and 11 to each control's Tag property that you want updated. You can set this property through code or set the property in the designer.

You are also free to change the values of the Tag property as you see fit. Just make sure the index checks in the code line up with the tag values you choose!